# Find next input field of specific class

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-selectors

I have several divs with two input fields each, like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            <input type="text" class="first" id="first_1" />
            <input type="text" class="second" id="second_1" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            <input type="text" class="first" id="first_2" />
            <input type="text" class="second" id="second_2" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So let's say I have the inputfield with id `second_1`, and assign some value to it:

```
$("#second_1").val("Hello");
```

How can I find the next input field with the class `"first"`? Keep in mind that I don't know its ID, it's not necessarily `first_2`.

So in other words, I want to assign a value to `first_2` as well, but without knowing its ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
var nextFirst = $("#second_1").closest('content').next().find('.first');
```

Use `closest(..).next()` to get the next row of inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Using `parents().next().find(...).first()` you can then find the next input with class`"first"` no matter how deep in the HTML tree is, nor the class or type of your parent elements.

```
$('#second_1').parents().next().find(".first").first().val("Hello");
```

```js
$('#second_1')
  .val("Starting here")
  .parents().next().find(".first").first().val("Hello");
```

```css
div { padding: 2px; }
#wrapper { border: 1px grey solid; }
.subcontent { border: 1px grey dashed; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
        <input type="text" class="first" id="first_1" />
        <input type="text" class="second" id="second_1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
        <input type="text" class="first" id="first_2" />
        <input type="text" class="second" id="second_2" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
        <input type="text" class="first" id="first_3" />
        <input type="text" class="second" id="second_3" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <input type="text" class="first" id="first_4" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <input type="text" class="first" id="first_5" />
  <input type="text" class="second" id="second_5" />
</div>
```

Comment: It works pretty well and it should be the accepted answer as the one did not work in all cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a top-down approach. Approach it from **parent** containers using [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```
$('.content:has(#first_1)').nextAll('.content:has(.first)').find('.first');
```

```js
console.log($('.content:has(#first_1)').nextAll('.content:has(.first)').find('.first'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            <input type="text" class="first" id="first_1" />
            <input type="text" class="second" id="second_1" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            <input type="text" class="first" id="first_2" />
            <input type="text" class="second" id="second_2" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. How does this work. Wouldn't `.content:has(#first_1)` exclude `#first_2` from the set?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini, no, it is not even including its children. Its saying, get me the .content element which **has** a #first_1

Comment: Right, but wouldn't that return only 1 element. Meaning that the `next(..)` would return 0?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini, it would return the next parent div. That is why I have find('.first') at the end

Comment: OOHHH!! I get it now, because you're using `has`. I haven't used that before. Very good :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var myInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("first");
for (var i = 0; i < myInputs.length; ++i) {
    var item = myInputs[i];  
    item.value = 'your value';
}
```

```js
            var myInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("first");
   for (var i = 0; i < myInputs.length; ++i) {
    var item = myInputs[i];  
    item.value = 'your value';
   }
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            <input type="text" class="first" id="first_1" />
            <input type="text" class="second" id="second_1" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            <input type="text" class="first" id="first_2" />
            <input type="text" class="second" id="second_2" />
        </div>
    </div>
```